# can't execute conky on docker

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, conky

I try to execute conky on my container (docker) for monitoring it with ssh tunnel. 
If I try to execute conky on my admin server it's okay but on my container I can't !

pc --> admin server --> container

I've installed libimlib2-dev but I get again this error:

```
Conky: can't open display: 
***** Imlib2 Developer Warning ***** :
    This program is calling the Imlib call:
    imlib_context_free();
    With the parameter:
    context
    being NULL. Please fix your program.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if SSH X forwardings is set up correctly by running some classic X clients like `xeyes` or `xclock` within your container.  If they run with no problem but only Conky fails, then that might be a bug of Conky and you might need to contact its developers.

Comment: if i try  that ssh USER@62.200.227.219 ssh USER@127.0.0.1 -p 8888 -Y xclock
i get Error: Can't open display:

Comment: i try something  i've recovered my contenair on my pc  i try to display xclock and everything doing fine .

Comment: i try to display xclock on my admin server and it's okai

Comment: so i think the probleme is on ssh

Comment: Yeah, seems like X-forwarding is not working correctly.  By the way, what is `ssh USER@62.200.227.219 ssh USER@127.0.0.1 -p 8888 -Y xclock` ?  Are there any reason you cannot simply run `ssh -p 8888 -Y USER@62.200.227.219 xclock` ?

Comment: i cant do what i want to do because is not possible  for the moment with my hosting

Comment: Then please follow these steps http://serverfault.com/questions/53080/how-to-enable-ssh-x11-forwarding-through-additional-server If it doesn't work well, I'd advise you to post it as a new and independent question since it's no longer related to Docker.